# How to control/adjust all user calendars en masse in G-Suite?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have well over 200 users in G-Suite, each with their own active calendar.

**Q: How to change settings on all of them at once?**

For example, we need them all to be publicly viewable (it's OK, I understand the implications), and by default every new one is private.

P.S. I have written about a dozen GAS apps, so I'm down with the API as needed.
P.S.S. I have highest access/permissions, and can 'see' all the calendars I need to manage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set proper ACLs to each calendar, assigning the "reader" role to the "default" (public) scope.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl#resource